# UI Autocomplete multiple combo box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, autocomplete, el

I have a problem here and I am a new to jquery autocomplete combo box.

Here we are adding combo boxes dynamically. My autocomplete feature is working fine in all combo boxes but I am not able to retain the values on the page when I come back to that page again.

Below is the sample code.

```
 _createAutocomplete: function() {

              var selected = this.element.children(":selected");
              var value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
              var x = this.element[0].id;     //we get id's of combo boxes like Comobox-0,Comobox-1,Comobox-2...etc
              var status = x.substr(x.length - 1);  // The values will be like 0,1,2 .. in strings etc
              var istatus = parseInt(status);  // parsing to int


              this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .attr( "title", '<fmt:message key="page.claim.personalclaimnotification.injury.select_info" />' )
                <%--.val("${claimNotificationForm.chattels[ss].objectValue}")  --%>
                .val(value)   // This is responsible for retaining the values on the page
                .attr("maxlength", 256)
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                  delay: 0,
                  minLength: 3,
                  source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
                })
```

In the above code, you can see that  **.val(value)** which is responsible for retaining the values on the page.

If the user selects the already existing values in the list then the below code will retains the values on the page.

```
var selected = this.element.children(":selected");
var value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
```

Here my requirement is that if the user given value is not present in the list, then that value is taken as a value.
so I tried to retain the value from the form bean.So I tried something like below.

```
var x = this.element[0].id;     //we get id's of combo boxes like Comobox-0,Comobox-1,Comobox-2...etc
      var status = x.substr(x.length - 1);  // The values will be like 0,1,2 .. in strings etc
      var istatus = parseInt(status);  // parsing to int
```

Then I used the below one to pick the value from the collection dynamically but this is not working..

```
  .val("${claimNotificationForm.chattels[istatus].objectValue}")
```

The above code is working with indexes 0,1,2.. but not with variable istatus.

```
.val("${claimNotificationForm.chattels[0].objectValue}")  
  .val("${claimNotificationForm.chattels[1].objectValue}")  
  .val("${claimNotificationForm.chattels[2].objectValue}")
```

How can I make it work so that it picks from the form bean dynamically with el expressions in jsp.